# In 3D coordination system, how to know that a given point is within provided 8 points?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

I have a question in geometry. I have been given a point P(x,y,z) and I want to know that whether this point P is within a set of other points or not? The other points are having following properties.

There would be exactly 8 points in 3D coordinate system. These 8 points will make a cube in 3D. 4 points will make a upper part of the cube and other four points will make lower part of the cube.

But the upper part (Upper 4 points) of the cube is not in same plane and so creates a surface (most probably curved surface).

[image]

Comment: You're missing some information. 8 points are not enough to create the example in the OP. You either need many more points or at least four equations to define the surface plane. Using 8 points will not provide a complete solution.

Comment: @Paul Sasik,
Thanks for the help.

But, here we have only 8 points in 3D. 4 points defines bottom of the cube and they all having same value for z-coordinate (And that would be 0, so bottom 4 points would always be in XY plane). Now for upper 4 points, they will have same X and Y coordinate values as their corresponding bottom points - but may have different Z values.

Can't we have a way to find a point between such surfaces?

As you suggested, can you please guide me how those additional equations would be? And when those equations are provided, how they can be used to solve such problem?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know. The main issue is that you simply cannot plot the curve plane sample in the OP w/o more data. 8 points even if some of the coordinates are shared could only produce a shape with straight lines connecting the points. You need to go and ask for more detail or clarification. It's possible that an approximate solution is good enough.

Comment: If you have some freedom to choose the form of the top surface, one semi-obvious choice would be to use bilinear interpolation to express the `z` in terms of `x` and `y`.  This gives you a curved surface whose edges are straight, and generalizes the planar case, in the sense that in the special case where all 4 of the top vertices *are* coplanar, you get a perfectly planar top surface.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation, for example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

1. as mentioned before you do not have enough information for your shape description

   - this means that you do not know how the top of your box/cube looks like
   - therefore you cannot determine if point is in or out precisely
   - with 8 points you can do only this (thick lines) [image: cuboid]
   - if you want the curvature surface then you need to add more info
2. add function Z=f(X,Y) for the curved surface

   - from this is easy
   - if X,Y is outside bounding area point is out
   - else if Z < 0 or Z > f(X,Y) point is out
   - else point is inside
3. function Z=f(X,Y) construction

   - you have to know more about the shape
   - for example the contour lines (more points)
   - or few point along the surface
   - normal vector on some point ...
   - for example something like this [image: cuboid]
   - now add parameters U,V (X,Y) but with range `<0,1>`
   - this will make the equations easier to solve
   - name the known points
   - [image: cuboid]
   - now write generic polynomial equation Z=F(U,V)
   - the higher the order the more accurate it is but also need more points/info
   - `Z=a0+a1*U+a2*U*U+a3*U*U*U+b0+b1*V+a2*V*V+a3*V*V*V`
   - can add also the derivation by U and V
   - `Z/dU=a1+2*a2*U+3*a3*U*U`
   - `Z/dV=b1+2*b2*V+3*b3*V*V`
   - now when you have the generic equations write the boundary conditions equations

     ```
     Z(0.0,0.0)=A.z; Z/dU(0.0,0.0)=A.nu; Z/dV(0.0,0.0)=A.nv; 
     Z(0.0,1.0)=B.z; Z/dU(0.0,1.0)=B.nu; Z/dV(0.0,1.0)=B.nv; 
     Z(1.0,1.0)=C.z; Z/dU(1.0,1.0)=C.nu; Z/dV(1.0,1.0)=C.nv; 
     Z(1.0,0.0)=D.z; Z/dU(1.0,0.0)=D.nu; Z/dV(1.0,0.0)=D.nv; 
     Z(0.5,0.5)=E.z; Z/dU(0.5,0.5)=E.nu; Z/dV(0.5,0.5)=A.nv;
     ```
   - solve this system of equations to get ai,bi coefficients
   - number of unknowns must be less or equal to distinct equations
   - so add/remove degree of polynomial to match the data you have !!!
   - if the shape is too complicated you can also add combinations of U,V into polynomial
   - like `...+c11*U*V+c12*U*V*V+c21*U*U*V+...`
   - a0+b0 is single unknown!

Comment: @BharatMori the equations are quite simple (especially when parameter = 0) but if you want to solve this algebraically and quickly (so you can later only add the data to solution) then use some math solving tool (I prefer derive for windows ... cause I am used to it from MS-DOS times ...)

Answer (score 0):

Rotate/shear the cube and point until the sides are orthogonal to the axes, and then perform a bounds check.

Comment: thanks for the help. Here, we can easily check whether a given point is in XY coordinate system or not - because it forms a quadrilateral on XY plane. But, when we will project a point on z-axis, it would really becomes difficult to say that whether the point a withing a limit (of Z axis) or not. Because the upper part of the cube is a surface and not a plane. But, if you think there is still way, please explain it in detail or direct me towards proper solution anywhere on the web. Once again, thanks for your help.